# Derivative find the slope of the graph of f(x) = 2x-3 at the point (2,1)

Tags: calculus

[image]

I am learning derivative and I don't quite understand as 2 delta x / delta x as x approaches 0 becomes 2/1 = 2 (as highlighted in red)

Can anyone explain?

Comment: $\Delta x$ is not exactly zero, so you can cancel them out $2\Delta x / \Delta x = 2$

Comment: (As a side note, the slope of any linear function is the coefficient of $x$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we write down $$\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = L$$

we are not interested in what happens at the point $x = a$, which can be seen from the $\epsilon -\delta$ definition:

$$\forall\epsilon >0:\exists\delta >0: \forall x\in dom(f): 0 < |x-a|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)- L | <\epsilon$$

We are interested in what happens in a neighbourhood of that point, but not in the point itself.

Therefore, when we have something like:

$$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{2\Delta x}{\Delta x}$$ we can just cancel the $\Delta x$, since it is considered non zero, but a number close to zero.

Comment: so in this case i should treat 2 delta x / delta x as 2a/a and therefore the result is 2/1 = 2?

Comment: Yes. Since delta x is not equal to zero, by definition of limit, otherwise you can't cancel because 0/0 does not make sense.

Comment: delta x -> 0, indicates as x approaches zero, therefore we consider x as a non-zero value?

Comment: Basically, yes, you can consider it as non zero, because when you take the limit of a point, you are not interested in what the function does in that point. According to the definition of limit, the function doesn't even have to be defined in 0 to find the limit there.